# Род существительных

Tags: морфология

К какому роду относятся несклоняемые существительные "Чили" и "колибри"?

Answer (score 2):

Однозначного ответа нет. Надо смотреть контекст употребления.
"Чили" может быть и среднего рода (государство) и женского (республика).
"Колибри" может быть и мужского (самец колибри) и женского (самка колибри). Орфографический словарь, правда, исходит из единственного предположения, что это "птица", поэтому ставит исключительно женский род, но тот же толковый словарь с ним не соглашается (как я и, впрочем) :)